# React: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError) : dispatch is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting an error in react
redux
like:`    .catch((err) => {
dispatch({
type: POST_ERROR,
payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
});
});
};

`
where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share your entire component?

If you're using hooks, you're probably missing `const dispatch = useDispatch();`.

If you are in "class" mode, the function is available from the store `store.dispach()`

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow#dispatch